# Module dependency leads to Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug' in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, module

I tried to add a module to an Android project and make the main module dependent on it and I got this error:

> Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I have a project with the main module app and added a module mylib and app depends on mylib.

Android Studio 1.2.2.

settings.gradle:

`include ':app', ':mylib'`

build.gradle from app:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

...

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':mylib')
}
```

build.gradle from mylib:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}
```

The JAVA_HOME variable:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40
```

The problem starts when I add line compile project(':mylib') to build.gradle, sometimes when I rebuild the project, but always when I try to run it. The VERSION_1_8 statements don't solve the problem.

What can be wrong? Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: is `mylib` intended to be a java library/JAR or an Android library/AAR?

Comment: @emerssso mylib is intended to be a Java library/JAR and was created with File | New | New Module ...     Java Library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem and I found the solution from this pure java unit tests tutorial, it said Android currently support is Java 1.7.

[Adding pure Java unit tests to an Android project](http://www.jedidja.ca/adding-pure-java-unit-tests-to-an-android-project/)

In short, just set your java lib module to 1.7, so your build.gradle in mylib may like this.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.7
    targetCompatibility = 1.7
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: I tried the 1.7 version and it works. Great. Thanks a lot. I am still confused though, because I have specified Java version 1.7 and I am using Java 1.8 (with JAVA_HOME pointing to JDK 1.8). Well anyway, it works, so I can continue.

Comment: You are just telling JDK8 to compile as JDK7 to make it compatible w/ Android. It succeeds probably because your library uses no JDK8-only features. The trick would be if your library used JDK8-only features and wouldn't be able to compile as JDK7. To do that requires using https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue happend with me, i did just two easy steps and my issue was gone:

1) build -> clean project
2) build -> rebuild project